# system call to gnuplot from php to generate plot?

Tags: php, gnuplot, system-calls

So, I am using a php program to read a file, make some changes and then write it to a new file.  After that, I call gnuplot, using a system call:

```
system('cat sarx.conf | /usr/bin/gnuplot');
```

`sarx.conf` has the gnuplot commands to generate the plot. The problem is if run my php from the command line (its on a linux server) it generates the image and stores it on the disk. But when I do the same thing by running the php on my browser it generates the image and tries to spit it out on the browser without actually storing it on disk.

Things i tried:

1. I though i might have had issues with permission settings but it didn't help.
2. I also hard coded the path where I want the image to be in `sarx.conf`.  That didn't help     either.
3. I also tried looking for it in the tmp directory --- no luck!!

Does anyone have any ideas on how can I get this to work?  I need to store this image on disk so that my website can grab it to show the plot later. Is there any php stuff which can grab the image and write it to disk?

Comment: Ok i got it to work if it helps someone in future

this is what i used:

exec('cat sarx.conf | /usr/bin/gnuplot');

and make sure the folder is writable. The neat thing it overwrites the file so if you are doing something like plot on web page that takes in new data ever second or so you can have the php to point to a definate path and grab the image. I was doing heatmaps !!

Answer (score 1):

There is a great LGPL-licensed PHP interface to gnuplot here: http://www.liuyi1.com/PHP-GNUPlot/

Here is how you could do something similar:

```
$my_file = tempnam();
$handle = popen('gnuplot', 'w');
fwrite($this->ph, "Run some gnuplot commands here\n");
fwrite($this->ph, "set term png\n");
fwrite($this->ph, "set output ".$my_file."\n");
fwrite($this->ph, "replot\n");
flush($handle);
pclose($handle);
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($my_file));
header('Content-Type: image/png');
print file_get_contents($my_file);
unlink($my_file);
```